# NSNotificationCenter equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, nsnotificationcenter

Recently I switched from Cocos2d-iPhone to Cocos2d-x. When writing Objective-C code I find `NSNotificationCenter` very useful in a few situations. I want to use something similar in a Cocos2d-x project written in C++.

I don't think writing my own relatively simple NotificationCenter would be too difficult. Before I re-invent the wheel I thought it appropriate to ask: **What is the equivalent of NSNotificationCenter when writing C++ code that runs on Android and iOS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [CCNotificationCenter](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.1.4/da/d45/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_notification_center.html) class in cocos2d-x.